# Reverse bundle install --without env through bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, continuous-integration, bundler, build-server

I've inherited a project that used to have a build script that `bundle install`ed with the `--without env` flag. Now I need that `env`.

I removed the `--without` flag from the build script, but those preferences are cached by bundler in `.bundle/config`. The build server has some confusing auto-caching of dependencies itself, and I have no idea where the `.bundle/config` is located.

Is there an bundler invocation capable of unsetting these `--without` preferences? A `--with` would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While undocumented in the `bundle install` help, `bundle config` notes you can reset or unset the `without` flag via `bundle config without newenv` and `bundle config --delete without` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove the `.bundle` directory and reinstall. The only reason I'd hesitate to do this is if you have versions of gems that are no longer available. You could always move it first to test:

```
mv .bundle _bundle
bundle install
```

If that works, you can remove the temporary `_bundle` directory, or whatever you've called it.

If it screws up, you can always restore it:

```
rm -rf .bundle
mv _bundle .bundle
```

Comment: That would involve messing with the `.bundle` folder manually--something I can't do. I need an bundler-CLI solution.

Comment: The `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` should have all the information required to re-generate the contents of the `.bundle` directory, but if you're prevented from messing with it because of policy, you might have to go about this the hard way.